# Compile time check of whether a method defined as virtual

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

I'm trying to come up with a way of checking in the derived class whether a method of the base class is defines as 'virtual' . Basically I would like to have the following code:

```
class A {
  virtual void vfoo() {}
  void foo() {}
  virtual ~A() {}
};

class B : public A {
  virtual void vfoo() {
    MAGIC_CHECK(m_pA->vfoo()); // succeed
    // code
    m_pA->vfoo();
    // code
  }
  virtual void foo() {
    MAGIC_CHECK(m_pA->foo()); // fail compilation because foo is not virtual!
    // code
    m_pA->foo();
    // code
  }
  A * m_pA;
};
```

The question is, how do I implement this MAGIC_CHECK?
One solution for this could be using -Woverloaded-virtual compilation flag.
Can anyone suggest a solution that will not involve this flag?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++03 standard, it's **not possible** to check if a method is declared as `virtual` or not.
You may follow,

- coding standards
- peer review
- possibly some static analysis tool

Answer (score 3):

In C++11 it's possible to add `override` at the end of the function declaration in the `class` and it will yield a warning if the function doesn't override anything:

```
class B : public A {
  virtual void vfoo() override { //OK
  }
  virtual void foo() override { //error
  }
};
```

Comment: Will it check `virtual`ness also ?

Comment: @iammilind oh, yes... it will break the build if the base method is not virtual.

Comment: I mean suppose `A::foo()` and `B::foo()` matches the syntax, but they `A::foo()` is not declared as `virtual`, then will it give compiler error? I am asking, because I have less knowledge of this feature.

Comment: @iammilind yes. See the link.

Comment: Visual Studio has supported the `override` keyword since 2005.

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with this feature in C++11.
Assume I modify the requirement to something slightly different:
Can I somehow check in compile time that the class A (in the example) is "interface"? By interface I mean that all its methods are pure virtual.
Is this possible w/o C++11 features?

Comment: @VadimS. not that I'm aware of. Might worth asking a new question.